# Importing Rx.Disposable in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

How do I correctly import Disposable in my TS file:

```
import { Disposable } from 'rxjs'
import { Disposable } from 'rxjs/Rx'
import * as Rx from 'rxjs'
```

Then

```
Rx.Disposable() or Disposable.create() etc...
```

None of these options works. I usually end up with an error such as:

```
Rx has no exported member 'Disposable'
```

I have used typings such:

```
typings install dt~rx --global
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah.. I was semi correct in the syntax but Disposable has been renamed to Subscription in [beta 5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md)